# building modernizr on the windows command line

Tags: javascript, windows, cmd, modernizr

So I followed the docs here:
https://github.com/modernizr/modernizr

1) cloned the repo using npm.
2) ran `npm install` inside modernizr to install its dependencies.
3) tried to run `./bin/modernizr -c lib/config-all.json`

I am getting an error:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I am assuming that this has to do with the windows command line not understanding that I am trying to execute the file at that location. How can I do step 3 on cmd?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same error: it is something else which is not installed for us on Windows. When I find it, I will post the information here.

Answer (score 4):

Here we go. You need to run the modernizr bin from within node.

```
node .\bin\modernizr -c .\lib\config-all.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the instructions in PowerShell. It does a better job of support *nix-style syntax and commands than the Command Prompt.

Comment: Where do I get powershell? Sorry, I am not much of a windows command line guy.

Comment: Just hit the Windows key, search for PowerShell, and it'll show up.

Comment: Ok, I tried in powershell, doesn't seem to work. I mean, it doesn't throw an error but it just tries to open the file.... Appreciate the responses so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Git Bash (part of Git for Windows) or (iof you feel like going in the front door) Minimalist GNU For Windows (http://www.mingw.org/) It works fine.